# Workaround to use a .Net Framework library in Portable Class Library

Tags: .net, portable-class-library

I have a .Net Framework dll library.
I need to use it inside a Windows 8 Store App (Desktop, not WRT) but searching on different forums it seems i have to build a bridge by a PCL library.
Is it the right way?

I can't find a tutorial/example, can anybody show me how can i do?
Thanks

Comment: You simply cannot.

Comment: I tried to refer .net framework dll inside a pcl project, so win8app project refers to pcl library: methods are called correctly and work!. Only one issue is .net framework dll refers to a further external native dll, which gives me "badimage format exception" when is called by main .net framework dll. Scenario too complicated, i know :)